# Premium Young Chicken packed in broth

Tags: chicken, freezing

Can I freeze a Tyson Premium Young Chicken packed in broth? I bought a twin pack of Tyson's Premium Young Chickens at Walmart. They have a broth packed in them that makes the packages resemble water balloons. Will the broth burst the sealed plastic liner if I freeze one? Thanks for your help. Jw

Answer (score 1):

Usually plastic wrapping doesn't burst from freezing, since its somewhat stretchable (unlike, say, glass). Even if it does burst, it's going to tear a seam or some weak spot—there shouldn't be an explosion.

There is an easy safeguard to take though—just put a gallon freezer bag around it (squeeze out as much air as you can). Or sit it in a container to catch any drippings.